# get object parameter from onclicked button

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

**i create a menu with button to choose one of categories :**

```
String text;
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

Button button1 = new Button("Hi");
button1.setOnAction(event -> text = button1.getText());
Button button2 = new Button("Bye");
button2.setOnAction(event -> text = button2.getText());
```

now i create an object and sent "text" variable as input

```
Board board = new Board(30, text);
board.create;
'do something'
```

in this code "text" is null when board created and make error.
how can i fix it to put variable as input of object correctly ??

Comment: Your question is not clear, at least not to me. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're trying to accomplish and add a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: can you help me now ?

Comment: Sounds like you should either delay creating the `Board` until one of the buttons are fired, or you should add a method to `Board` which accepts the text and invoke said method when one of the buttons are fired.

Comment: exactly , how can i do this?

Comment: Well, you know how to create classes and, by extension, I assume you know how to create methods. You also to know how to invoke methods and how to do something when a button is clicked. With all that in mind, you should be able to implement either of the options I mentioned. If, however, you're having a _specific_ problem please [edit] your question to add a [mre] demonstrating said problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are searching:

```
Button button1 = new Button("Hi");
    grid.add(button1, 0, 0);
    button1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            text = button1.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    });
```

However try running this to understand how javafx works a bit better...

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.show();
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 400, 275);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    Label label = new Label("Test Label:");
    grid.add(label, 0, 0);

    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    grid.add(userTextField, 0, 1);

    Button btn = new Button("Update Label");
    grid.add(btn, 1, 1);

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("button pressed, textField value: " + userTextField.getText());
            label.setText(userTextField.getText());
        }
    });

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

I think you will find this [link from oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/form.htm) quite useful, to start.